# Which kind of math font set is used in the picture?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

[image]

I like the math font set used in the picture very much, so what is the math font set name and where can I find the font set package or LaTeX Release, thanks.

PS: Is is not the MathTimeProII.

Comment: No, it isn't MathTimePro, but it's some kind of Times anyway; can you point to a source?

Comment: Did you have a browse here: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html to see if you could spot it? There are a number of times-like fonts such as "New TX" listed there.

Comment: Some pdf readers let you find out which fonts are used in the document. If you cannot determine the fonts, perhapps you can make the pdf source available so others can give it a shot.

Comment: Em..., I have uploaded a pdf file "MAXIMUM LIKELIHOOD ESTIMATION" to my SkyDrive [link](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=B279BBF95FFA1509&id=B279BBF95FFA1509%21278), in this pdf file, font name ``MTEX MTMS MTSYN'' are listed in the pdf attri dialog, but anything useful to me was founded when I tried to use ``MTEX MTMS MTSYN'' as the searching keywords. The only really truth is the math font looks pretty like MathTimeProII, but the curly braces in this file are different from the braces used in MTPII obviously.

Comment: The pdf file's meta data says that it was compiled in 2004. This piece of information, together with the presence of font names such as MTEX, MTMS, and MTSYN (as well as a few more fonts) seems to indicate that the first "generation" of MathTime fonts -- rather than the current version, which are called "MathTime Professional II" -- were used to compile this document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the old Y&Y MathTime Complete font, the predecessor of MathTimeProII. Since Y&Y is no more, there is no way to buy this font anymore, unless you can find a second-hand disk somewhere.