# Which math font is this?

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to find out what font this is. It seems to have support for math mode. 
[image]

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98368/which-kind-of-math-font-set-is-used-in-the-picture?rq=1.

Comment: Looks like Palatino. Try `\usepackage{mathpazo}`.

Comment: I'm guessing [`mathpazo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathpazo). See [Suggest a “nice” font family for my basic LaTeX template (text and math)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59702/5764)